# XOR operation on two checkboxes in Salesforce

Tags: community, formula, validation

I need to make a selection of Gender. [ ] Female [ ] Male.

Either one of them must be selected.

I used following formula for validating.

```
AND( Female__c = TRUE ,  Male__c  = TRUE )
```

Using this, I can select only one but I am unable to get exact functionality it is doing?

Answer (score 8):

Validation rules trigger when the result is true, so you're looking for one of:

```
NOT(Female__c = Male__c)

-- or --

Female__c != Male__c
```

This will result in the validation rule triggering only when both or neither are selected. You don't need to compare checkboxes to true or false, by the way, since they're already Boolean values.

If you want a truly XOR-feeling way of doing it (say, if you needed this for a picklist), then you'd want:

```
(Male__c && Female__c) || (NOT(Male__c) && NOT(Female__c))

-- or --

OR(AND(Male__c, Female__c), AND(NOT(Male__c), NOT(Female__c)))
```

You can also use some basic math to make sure just one box is checked:

```
1 != IF(Male__c,1,0) + IF(Female__c,1,0)
```

This is probably the closest to a "pure" implementation of XOR you'll find.

Comment: I didn't the question properly, totally missed the point :)

Comment: @Bachovski It's okay. I've done that before, too. Certainly does make one feel sheepish!

Comment: It's what happens when a developer is stuck looking into data migration spreadsheets! :)